# Mocking React Query useQueryClient to test cached data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, react-query

I use a custom hook to share an `increment` function accross my app (it increments quantities in a shopping cart).

What that function does :

- gets a data object from a React Query cache
- increments the data `quantity` property
- makes some API call via React Query `useMutation` then, on success, updates the React Query cache

After that, the components reads the React Query cart cache and updates the UI with the new quantity.

The hook does the job and finally the cache is updated as expected.

Now, I try to test the hook in a component to check that the UI is updated accordingly.

The API call is mocked using `msw`. Its returned value is used to update the cache :

```
  rest.put(`${api}/carts/1`, (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(ctx.json({ data: [{ id: 1, quantity: 2 }] }));
  })
```

I also mocked the react-query `queryClient.setQueryData` and `getQueryData` functions so I can test their returns values.

```
jest.mock("react-query", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("react-query"),
  useQueryClient: () => ({
    setQueryData: jest.fn(),
    getQueryData: jest
      .fn()
      .mockReturnValueOnce({ data: [{ id: 1, quantity: 1 }] })
      .mockReturnValueOnce({ data: [{ id: 1, quantity: 2 }] }),
  }),
}));
```

Finally, I test the UI that should updates with the new quantity, but the mocked `getQueryData` always return the original `quantity: 1`, even with multiple call.

Now I'm not sure I have the right approach for that test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you need to mock `setQueryData` and `getQueryData` ? Mocking the network layer with `msw` should be all you need. If you wrap your rendered hook in a `QueryClientProvider` with a `queryClient`, that will be populated with the mocked data returned from `msw`, and `queryClient.getQueryData` will be able to read it without mocking it.

Comment: To display some cart data, I `queryClient.getQueryData(["cart"])` in my component, just before calling the hook. That's why I had to mock the `useQueryClient` in my test. Maybe It could be simpler if the cart datas were only queried from the hook itself ? I try to find a way to just rely on `React Query` to display and update my cart datas. But maybe I'm not on the right path.

Comment: yeah I don't think its advised to call queryClient.getQueryData during rendering - that's what the useQuery hook is for.

Comment: Done ! The test is passing now... except when it fails, occasionally. About one time out of 10, the `useQuery` on the cart resource returns `undefined`. It's not related to my original post but if you have an idea. I accept your answer anyway. Thanks for you help !

Answer (score 2):

Suppose I just want to mock getQueryData for a particular test case and leave the other functions like invalidateQueries, cancelQuery, and setQueryData as it is, then how can modify this mock function?
This is what I wrote. But getting this

```
TypeError: queryClient.cancelQueries is not a function
```

```
jest.mock("@tanstack/react-query", () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual("@tanstack/react-query"),
    useQueryClient: () => ({
        // setQueryData: jest.fn(() => ({ data: [{ label: 'Blue', id: 34 }] })),
        // cancelQueries: jest.fn(),
        // invalidateQueries: jest.fn(),
        ...jest.requireActual("@tanstack/react-query").useQueryClient(),
        getQueryData: jest
            .fn()
            .mockReturnValueOnce({ data: [{ id: 1, quantity: 1 }] })
            .mockReturnValueOnce({ data: [{ id: 1, quantity: 2 }] }),
    }),
}));
```